# Unable to pass parameter in onclick event handler - React

Tags: reactjs

I observe an issue where when I click on delete button, it errors out saying handleDelete is undefined. However, I have defined it. Can someone please suggest me on how to resolve the issue?

I tried to put the delete button outside map function and it works. However, when I use delete button inside map function, it doesn't.

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import { v1 as uuid } from "uuid";

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          list: [],
          item: "",
          id: uuid(),
        };
      }
      handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          item: e.target.value,
        });
      };
      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newItem = {
          item: this.state.item,
          id: this.state.id,
        };

        const newList = [...this.state.list, newItem];
        this.setState({
          list: newList,
          item: "",
          id: uuid(),
        });
      };
      handleDelete = (id) => {
        console.log("delete button pressed");
      };
      clearList = () => {
        this.setState({
          list: [],
        });
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input
                placeholder="enter list name"
                value={this.state.item}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <button type="submit">add item</button>
            </form>
            <ul>
              {this.state.list.map(function (element, id) {
                return (
                  <li key={id}>
                    <h5>{element.item}</h5>
                    <button type="button">edit</button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(id)}>delete</button>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.clearList}>
              clear list
            </button>

          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an arrow function in the map, you are missing the lexical bindings.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { v1 as uuid } from "uuid";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      item: "",
      id: uuid(),
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      item: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      item: this.state.item,
      id: this.state.id,
    };

    const newList = [...this.state.list, newItem];
    this.setState({
      list: newList,
      item: "",
      id: uuid(),
    });
  };
  handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log("delete button pressed");
  };
  clearList = () => {
    this.setState({
      list: [],
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            placeholder="enter list name"
            value={this.state.item}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">add item</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map((element, id) => {
            return (
              <li key={id}>
                <h5>{element.item}</h5>
                <button type="button">edit</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(id)}>delete</button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.clearList}>
          clear list
        </button>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```